# Javascript - É possível ter uma função de ordenação universal

Tags: javascript, classificação, callback

Eu tenho um objeto chamado relatorio e tenho um vetor de relatorio e preciso fazer diversas ordenações, então pensei em fazer uma função de ordenação que fosse "universal".
Queria poder passar o atributo a ser ordenado, de forma com que eu conseguisse reutilizar a função de ordenação diversas vezes.

Objeto:

```
 var relatorio = {
        ano: '',
        sigla: '',
        veiculo: '',
        qualis: '',
        fator: '',
        titulo: '',
        autores: ''
    };
```

Função de ordenação:

```
function ordena(vetor,attr) {
    vetor.sort(function(a,b) {
     return a.attr.localeCompare(b.attr);

    });
}
```

Exemplo: 
Ao chamar:

```
ordena(vetor,'ano');
```

Eu deveria ter como resultado o vetor ordenado pelo ano

Ao chamar:

```
ordena(vetor,'titulo');
```

Eu deveria ter como resultado o vetor ordenado pelo titulo

É possivel? Ou tenho q fazer uma função de ordenação específica para cada atributo?

Comment: No caso, "vetor" em `ordena(vetor,'ano');`seria "relatorio"?

Answer (score 0):

É possível. Você pode utilizar a [notação de colchete](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_colchete) juntamente do parâmetro `funcaoDeComparacao` para o método [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), aonde você deve definir a função de comparação acessando a propriedade do objeto dentro do *array*.

Pode ser assim:

```
function ordenacaoDinamica(propriedade) {
    return function (a,b) {
        if (a[propriedade] < b[propriedade]) return -1;
        if (a[propriedade] > b[propriedade]) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Para invocar a função:

```
relatorios.sort(ordenacaoDinamica("ano"));
relatorios.sort(ordenacaoDinamica("titulo"));
```

<sub>Caso queira ver um exemplo funcionando, clique em *Exibir trecho de código* abaixo e em seguida em *Executar*.</sub>

```js
function ordenacaoDinamica(propriedade) {
    return function (a,b) {
        if (a[propriedade] < b[propriedade]) return -1;
        if (a[propriedade] > b[propriedade]) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}

var relatorios = [
    {
        ano: '1990',
        sigla: 'ABC',
        veiculo: 'CD',
        qualis: 'FG',
        fator: 'HI',
        titulo: 'JK',
        autores: 'LM'
    },
    {
        ano: '1980',
        sigla: 'CDE',
        veiculo: 'FG',
        qualis: 'HI',
        fator: 'JK',
        titulo: 'LM',
        autores: 'NO'
    },
    {
        ano: '2010',
        sigla: 'AAA',
        veiculo: 'BBB',
        qualis: 'CCC',
        fator: 'DDD',
        titulo: 'EEE',
        autores: 'FFF'
    }
];

console.log(relatorios.sort(ordenacaoDinamica("ano")));
console.log(relatorios.sort(ordenacaoDinamica("titulo")));
```